# Amazon S3 publicly available tests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I had to write a bit of custom stuff on top of s3, where I later proxy traffic. Now I want to test that but with so many custom implemenations of amazons s3 and proxies, I was wondering if there are any publicly available tests, that I can just clone and run with pointing to my url to verify that all the basic functionalities are still functioning properly.

Do you know of any?

Thanks!

Comment: What " custom implemenations of S3 and proxies"? Test what?

Comment: @Marcin well, exactly that - s3. There are so many custom implementations and proxies of s3 - I'm sure there are some test scenarios, like store item, get item, check if everything is alright. Since all the implementations/proxies have to copy the API the tests on that could be reused

Comment: [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) is popular choice for testing and mocking aws resources.

Comment: Are you wanting to "test that S3 is up and running", or are you wanting to "test that your code is working"?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are wanting to test whether "Amazon S3 is available".

Amazon S3 is a regional based service. This means that is runs across multiple Availability Zones, where each Availability Zone is a separate data center (or sometimes multiple data centers). Amazon S3 is designed for 99.99% availability.

You can certainly monitor Amazon S3 yourself, but an alternative is to use **AWS Personal Health Dashboard**.

From [Getting started with the AWS Personal Health Dashboard - AWS Health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/getting-started-phd.html):

> You can use the AWS Personal Health Dashboard to learn about AWS Health events that can affect your AWS services or account. The Personal Health Dashboard presents information in two ways: a dashboard that shows recent and upcoming events organized by category, and a full event log that shows all events from the past 90 days.

From [Monitor for AWS Health events with Amazon CloudWatch Events - AWS Health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html):

> You can use Amazon CloudWatch Events to detect and react to changes for AWS Health events.

For example, you can configure Amazon SNS to send an email notification when an event occurs.